# Bound the maximal possible arithmetical error of primitive math. operations

Tags: java, precision

Is there any possibility to calculate the highest error of the sum or subtraction of two numbers with 7 fractional digits?

For example:

```
a=#.#######
b=#.#######
a+/-b = #.####### + / - epsilon
```

a and b are random numbers. I need an equation for an if-case if **a** or **b** are `equal to zero` or `equal to 1' <>epsilon`. I thougt if I math.ceil 'a' and math.floor b I get the maximal error. But it does not work.

It seems like that the error is everytimes something with `1.#####...E-6`. Can it get mathematically proofed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about IEEE 754:
The possible error (gap) depends on your floating point data type (i.e. float or double) and more importantly also depends on how far away your number is from zero. (nonuniform resolution)

Assuming you want to solve some programming problem:
In general, you deal with this issue by not using a simple equality comparer but define a domain specific epsilon in your comparisons:

```
// if(a == b)
if(Math.abs(a-b) < epsilon)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: hi. thx. its solved.. not pretty but it works... i just set epsilon to 0.000000...1. i never observe such small correct values.